# Temporary failure in name resolution when running Spring app with dockerized MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, docker, ubuntu

I have simple SpringBoot app with following configuration, running on Ubuntu 20.04

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

....

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And in application.properties `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://my_db:27017/test`

I'm not sure if that is relevant but I have some documents as well

```
@Repository
interface SomeDocumentRepository : CrudRepository<SomeDocument, String>

@Document
data class SomeDocument(
    @Id val id: String? = null,
    val name: String
)
```

And I'm running Mongo in docker container by executing
`docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name my_db mongo:latest`

However, when I start my Spring application, it crashes with
`com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: my_db: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Any idea what is wrong with that configuration? Why is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this means there is a problem with the nameserver resolvers you have configured for your server in **/etc/resolv.conf**. They may be unavailable or there may be a networking issue preventing connectivity to them.

This will resolve itself after a period of time but indicates a possible deeper problem that you may wish to contact your nameserver resolver provider about (often your web hosting company).